# Twitter API 1.1 Get Number of Times URL Mentioned? v. 1 works fine, can't find equivalent for 1.1

Tags: twitter

Using Twitter's API v 1 if I want to retrieve the number of times a URL was tweeted I simply GET the following, which returns the information in JSON...

http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?callback=?&url=google.com

I'm searching the documentation for 1.1 and cannot seem to find an equivalent... does one exist? Thanks!

Comment: Nobody has a response for this??

Comment: I found this which doesn't look promising... https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12643